# Casting Double Pointer and How to utilize in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, double-pointer

Here is basically a simple code of double pointer and what I am trying to use:

```
int argsCount = 1;
char **cmdArgs1 = malloc((argsCount + 1)*sizeof(char*));
```

I want to input values into the cmdArgs1 and here is basically what I am doing and causing seg fault

```
for(counter = 0; counter < argsCount; counter++)
{
    strcpy(cmdArgs1[counter],"ls");
}
```

I'm thinking that I can't use "cmdArg1[counter]" to copy to "ls" because the double pointer doesn't work that way? I'm not sure...

Even I think it's a bit vague, but I don't know how to phrase the question well, I will try to update based on the comment. Thx!

Comment: `cmdArgs1[counter]` isn't initialized. You mustn't refer to it until you assign to it a meaningful value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cmdArgs1` is a pointer to a pointer, meaning that it is not enough to allocate space for the array itself. You need to allocate space for the individual arrays of characters (or for the individual C string).

You can do it in a separate call of `malloc`

```
for(counter = 0; counter < argsCount; counter++)
{
    cmdArgs1[counter] = malloc(strlen("ls")+1); // +1 for null terminator
    strcpy(cmdArgs1[counter], "ls");
}
```

or with `strdup`:

```
for(counter = 0; counter < argsCount; counter++)
{
    cmdArgs1[counter] = strdup("ls");
}
```

In both cases your program is liable for `free`ing the elements of the array before `free`ing the array itself:

```
for(counter = 0; counter < argsCount; counter++)
{
    free(cmdArgs1[counter]);
}
free(cmdArgs1);
```

Comment: Don't you mean `strlen("ls")+1`? That's quite a different thing as `strlen("ls"+1)`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Absolutely! Thanks!